# Display html in a flutter widget on macOS app

Tags: html, flutter, macos, webview, widget

I am new to Flutter and I think that I need help.
I am writing a native **macOS** app with Flutter, and I need to **display** **HTML** contained in a String variable. I need to display it in a scrollable widget, such as SingleChildScrollView.
The HTML I need to print is collected via the Gmail API, so it is supposed to display emails from the API, written in HTML.

First I tried the libraries flutter_html and flutter_widget_from_html but they only work with basic HTML, when I am trying to display more heavy html, it crashes.

So I am now trying to display HTML via a **web view**, but I can't make them work with a native macOS app.
I tried with webview_flutter, which doesn't support macOS currently, so I moved to flutter_macos_webview, but it crashes when I try to open the web view. Here is the code.
The only thing that seems to work is the library desktop_webview_window, but it opens another window when I want an embedded widget, and I don't know how to execute local HTML contained in a string instead of launching a website

I hope it's clear, thanks for your help!

Here is the code of flutter_macos_webview that crashed when I launch the review.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter_macos_webview/flutter_macos_webview.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  Future<void> _onOpenPressed(PresentationStyle presentationStyle) async {
    final webview = FlutterMacOSWebView(
      onOpen: () => print('Opened'),
      onClose: () => print('Closed'),
      onPageStarted: (url) => print('Page started: $url'),
      onPageFinished: (url) => print('Page finished: $url'),
      onWebResourceError: (err) {
        print(
          'Error: ${err.errorCode}, ${err.errorType}, ${err.domain}, ${err.description}',
        );
      },
    );

    await webview.open(
      url: 'https://google.com',
      presentationStyle: presentationStyle,
      size: Size(400.0, 400.0),
      userAgent:
          'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1',
    );

    // await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
    // await webview.close();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          CupertinoButton(
            child: Text('Open as modal'),
            onPressed: () => _onOpenPressed(PresentationStyle.modal),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 16.0),
          CupertinoButton(
            child: Text('Open as sheet'),
            onPressed: () => _onOpenPressed(PresentationStyle.sheet),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flutter_widget_from_html_core: ^0.10.3` package to display `Html` in your app.

Or you can use `webview_flutter_plus 0.3.0+2` to create a webview to display the html

Comment: Not working too :(
It shows a blank page
Idk how to show you my html code because it is a very long String, but when I put it in an html viewer online it works, so I don't think that it is my html code that is broken, but instead that the plugins doesn't support heavy html

Comment: what html you want to show

Comment: then try using webview instead

Comment: that's why I am trying to do, but I can't achieve to make a webview embedded in a widget on a macOS native app

Comment: here is my html [link](https://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer/y2324234c)

Comment: this is a very heavy html

Comment: Use webview_flutter_plus 0.3.0+2 for this type of html

Comment: I have this error using webview_flutter_plus ; UnsupportedError (Unsupported operation: Trying to use the default webview implementation for TargetPlatform.macOS but there isn't a default one). I think Macs apps are not supported...

Answer (score 0):

here is an idea , why not create a temporarily html file then open it in browser like

```
import 'dart:html' as html;
html.window.open(url, name);
```

Comment: thank for your idea, but I need it to be in an embedded widget, not in another window or in the browser